# Como editar uma variável numérica para valores monetários em R$ no R?

Tags: r

Tenho a seguinte base de dados que pode ser acessada através do link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c1ecqf00tocljo8/internacoes_sc.xlsx?dl=0

Gostaria de saber como eu conseguiria alterar a variável `gasto` de  modo que aparecesse o símbolo monetário "R$". Queria que as observações tivessem na notação da moeda brasileira, como por exemplo R$ 3.455,93 ao invés de 3455.93 .

Tentei fazer pela função

```
library(stringr)

format_real <- function(values, nsmall = 0) {
  values %>%
    as.numeric() %>%
    format(nsmall = nsmall, decimal.mark = ",", big.mark = ".") %>%
    str_trim() %>%
    str_c("R$ ", .)
}

format_real(tabela$valor)
```

mas não consegui. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua função faz o que deseja:

```
v <- c(27568.2, 2649.45, 876)

format_real(v, 2)
#> [1] "R$ 27.568,20" "R$ 2.649,45"  "R$ 876,00"
```

Mas repare que os valores são convertidos para texto. Se quiser manter como valores numéricos, alterando apenas a exibição, pode criar uma classe e estabelecer métodos para ela. Por exemplo:

```
as.real <- function(x){
  if (!is.numeric(x)) stop("x precisa ser numérico")
  class(x) <- c("real", class(x))
  x
}

print.real <- function(x) {
  cat(paste0("R$ ", formatC(x, digits = 2, format = "f", big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")))
}

sum.real <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE, ...) {
  y <- NextMethod(x, na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  as.real(y)
}

vr <- as.real(v)

vr
#> R$ 27.568,20 R$ 2.649,45 R$ 876,00

sum(vr)
#> R$ 31.093,65
```

Casos em que um método próprio para a classe não foi definido, será usado o método para `numeric`:

```
mean(vr)
#> [1] 10364.55
```

Mas sempre pode usar o método para `print` para alterar a exibição do resultado:

```
as.real(mean(v))
#> R$ 10.364,55
```

Answer (score 5):

eu apliquei a função que vc elaborou e funcionou:

Ao importar sua base no Dropbox, eu atribui o nome de "internacoes":

Em seguida, rodei o seu código:

```
format_real <- function(values, nsmall = 0) {
  values %>%
    as.numeric() %>%
    format(nsmall = nsmall, decimal.mark = ",", big.mark = ".") %>%
    str_trim() %>%
    str_c("R$ ", .)
}
```

E por fim, apliquei a sua função à coluna "gasto" do dataset usando a função `mutate()`:

```
internacoes %>% 
  mutate(gasto = format_real(gasto))
```

Resultado:

```
# A tibble: 295 × 4
   code_muni n_internacoes gasto        geom 
   <chr>             <dbl> <chr>        <lgl>
 1 420005                1 R$ 0,00      NA   
 2 420010               53 R$ 28.674,17 NA   
 3 420020                3 R$ 2.644,52  NA   
 4 420030                1 R$ 0,00      NA   
 5 420040                1 R$ 0,00      NA   
 6 420050               22 R$ 19.940,99 NA   
 7 420055                1 R$ 0,00      NA   
 8 420060                1 R$ 4.535,77  NA   
 9 420070                1 R$ 0,00      NA   
10 420075                1 R$ 0,00      NA   
# … with 285 more rows
```

Comment: Por algum motivo funciona quando utilizar o operador `%>%` e quando usa o operador nativo `|>` não dá certo. Muito obrigada pela ajuda, Itamar.

Answer (score 4):

Poderia usar `scales`:

```
dplyr::mutate(internacoes, gasto = scales::number(gasto, prefix = "R$ ", big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","))
```

A vantagem de `scales` é que não precisa construir função alguma (claro que construir funções proporciona maior flexibilidade, mas para a maior parte dos problemas, creio fortemente que `scales` dá conta).

O pacote `scales` tem uma série de funções, como `scales::percent` que multiplica por 100  e insere o sufixo `%` automaticamente. Por exmeplo:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)

dplyr::mutate(df_1, x = scales::percent(x))

#         x  y
# 1    100% 11
# 2    200% 12
# 3    300% 13
# 4    400% 14
# 5    500% 15
# 6    600% 16
# 7    700% 17
# 8    800% 18
# 9    900% 19
# 10 1 000% 20
```

Também pode realizar arredondamento matemático com o argumento `accuracy`, semelhante ao argumento `digits` da função `base::round`. Na verdade, `digits` era o nome antigo de `accuracy`. Conforme documentação:

> **digits** Deprecated, use accuracy instead.

Também é muito usada junto ao `ggplot2` para edição de valores nos gráficos. Veja mais [aqui](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/04/scales-1-2-0/).